# Meteor method is not called on server in production

Tags: meteor

I have a method that is working well in dev, but as soon as I deploy then the method stops receiving calls.

console.log is called on client. I can see it in browser console. But server log does not have upsertTurn.

Anybody any ideas why or how to debug that?

Here's the example code:

**imports/api/turns.js:** (imported in client and server)

```
Meteor.methods({
  upsertTurn(turn) {
    console.log('upsertTurn', this.userId);
    if(this.userId) {
      return Turns.update(
        { _id: turn._id },
        { $set: _.omit(turn, '_id') },
        { upsert: true, multi: false }
      );
    }
  },
});
```

**UPDATE 1**:
I emptied the production database and it started to work...
It looks like the publish-composite publication is putting a high load on the server and then the method call computation hangs.

**UPDATE 2:**

```
export const OpcoTurns = (userId) => { return Turns.find( OpcoTurnsQuery( userId ) ); };

const OpcoTurnFlights = (turn) => {
  return Flights.find( TurnFlightsQuery( turn ), FlightsSort );
};

const TurnFlightsQuery = (turn) => {
  if(turn) {

    const turnEnd = m(turn.started).add(turn.duration, 'hours').toDate();
    return {
      $and: [{
        $or: [
          { itia: { $gt: turn.started } },
          { itis: { $gt: turn.started} }
        ]
      }, {
        $or: [
          { itia: { $lt: turnEnd } },
          { itis: { $lt: turnEnd } }
        ]
      }, {
        appType: new User().user.profile.appType
      }, {
        $or: [
          { turnID: null },
          { turnID: turn._id }
        ]
      }]
    };

    //example with values:
    // { $and: [{ $or: [ { itia: {$gt: Date("2016-06-30T14:47:48.536Z")}}, {itis: {$gt: Date("2016-06-30T14:47:48.536")}} ]}, { $or: [ {itia: {$lt: Date("2016-06-30T22:47:48.536Z")}}, {itis: {$lt: Date("2016-06-30T22:47:48.536Z")}} ] },{ appType: 0 }] }

  }
};

Meteor.publishComposite("OpcoTurnFlights", {
  find: function() {
    if(this.userId) return OpcoTurns(this.userId);
    return;
  },
  children: [
    { find: function(turn) { return OpcoTurnFlights(turn); } }
  ]
});
```

Comment: Could you also tell where this code is located?

Comment: I emptied production database and it started to work... Looks like aggregation methods make a high payload on the server and the method call computation hangs.

Comment: Better just delete this question, as it was just a mistake, and has no value remaining on SO

Comment: @Mikkel actually it has, because it's not a mistake, but an unexpected behavior of Meteor.
If there's a lot of data in the collection which has an aggregate subscription, then it hangs. If I had found this question in SO, I would not have spent 4 hours trying to figure out what's happening.

Comment: Did you try putting [this.unblock()](http://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html#DDPCommon-MethodInvocation-unblock) at the top of your method?

Comment: Also it's unclear from this discussion whether you have a different *subscription* running (not shown in your code) that uses the mongodb aggregation framework. Your method is not doing any aggregation.

Comment: @MichelFloyd great suggestion about this.unblock(). I added the aggregate subscription code.

Comment: Your subquery on publish-composite is quite complex and needs to be executed one parent document at a time. This could be extremely slow. Are `itia`, `itis`, `appType`, and `turnId` all indexed? Also why would you join a `Flight` with a null `turnId` to a parent `Turn` that has a `turnId` value? That shouldn't be a valid join.

Comment: @MichelFloyd Thank you. Now I understand... Actually `OpcoTurns` should be returning one Turn at a time. It should search then for all `Flights` that are not assigned to a turn (`turnId: null`) within a given timeframe... There'd be one turn and 50 flights, nothing more... Curiously, I didn't touch the `Flights` collection, something goes wrong in `Turns`, as it started to work well when I deleted everything from `Turns`...

Answer (score 0):

try put your code inside the try cath, then with console.log (e) I get you can see the error of having some

```
try {
    console.log('upsertTurn', this.userId);

if(this.userId) {

  return Turns.update(
    {
      _id: turn._id
    },
    {
      $set: _.omit(turn, '_id')
    },
    {
      upsert: true,
      multi: false
    }
  );
}
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but the method is not called at all... So there's no point in placing code within the method.

Answer (score 0):

According to the `publish-composite` docs, your `find`...

> Must return a cursor of second tier documents.

```
find: function() {
    if(this.userId) return OpcoTurns(this.userId);
    return;
  },
```

If `this.userId` is null, this will never return a cursor, and `publish-composite` probably detonates. This is the most immediately suspicious line here.

**Solution 1**: Don't use `publish-composite`. If you have to, fix this issue.

Also, I suspect you're sending a `turn` object in your `Meteor.call("upsertTurn", ...)` on the client. Are you doing anything with this `turn` object, including possibly adding fields that can't be serialized by EJSON?

**Solution 2**: Don't design the method to accept a whole document, ever.

Regarding emptying the database, it probably just reset the pattern of calls between authenticated and unauthenticated states. This can break/unbreak your `publish-composite`. It shouldn't actually have an impact performance-wise, since 50 documents is nothing in Mongo or Meteor.

Comment: Thank for the idea, but how do I fix the issue with `publish-composite`?